# Flutter package provider with templates

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to use provider with template, but Provider.of seems not working like that.

**Logs:**

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
>   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
>   following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown building
>   MyChildWidget(dirty): Error: Could not find the correct
>   Provider above this MyChildWidget Widget
>
> To fix, please:
>
> - Ensure the Provider is an ancestor to this MyChildWidget Widget
> - Provide types to Provider
> - Provide types to Consumer
> - Provide types to Provider.of()
> - Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
> - Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

Do you know any solution ?

**Sample to show the problem:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Provider<MyChildState>.value(
          value: MyChildState("Hello world !"),
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: MyChildWidget(),
          )),
    );
  }
}

abstract class MyParentWidget<State extends MyParentState> extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final State state = Provider.of(context);
    return Text(state.text);
  }
}

abstract class MyParentState {
  final String text;

  MyParentState(this.text);
}

class MyChildWidget<MyChildState> extends MyParentWidget{
}

class MyChildState extends MyParentState {
  MyChildState(String text) : super(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance over your code, I can see that you are passing `MyChildState("Hello world !")` as the value, but later in `MyParentWidget` class you are requesting a `State` object `final State state = Provider.of(context);`.

Try requesting `MyChildState` instead of `State`.

My first impression after reading your code is that you are coming from a different programming language and now you are trying Flutter. A friendly advice would be *keep everything as simple as possible*.

All the abstraction and how the code is organized might confuse you later when you review the code you wrote instead of helping you.

Comment: Yes i'm coming from Android. Here i would like to share UI logic with 'common widget' to inherit. I use bloc to provide stream<State> for each widget, but if 2 widgets have some common UI logic i would like to extract this logic inside parent widget (so parent will use parent state to apply common logic, and child can override this behavior for his changes).

Comment: But like you said, i can try to extract state provide from parent, each child recover his state with provider.of, and create methods in parent widget to call from childs.

Comment: I suggest you go out there and try a few tutorials and read about Flutter state management. Your perspective of Flutter apps is slightly confusing.
In my projects, I never used abstract classes for UI purposes, like having a parent and a child, and then the parent has some functionality that the child can override.
Usually, every Widget represents an element from the screen. You want to model it as a Widget that has children? Add a children argument in the constructor, like the `Column` widget does.
I recommend you go through the existing widgets' implementation to understand Flutter better

Comment: For example for 2 screens, i need to enter email, with showing error if regex wrong etc... So i'll create 'EmailWidget' and use it in 2 screens.
But if a third screen need to enter email but errors are showed with different text, i wouldn't duplicate all the widget, just rewrite method showing errors.

Comment: In this case i need common widget, but 'common state' is certainly the wrong way. For others case i need same state but some widgets with same behaviors need additionals infos, that's why i thought about override state without rewrite all the widget